# Beautifulsoup xml

Tags: python, xml, io, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use this code to add into an xml tree a simple info, which I have in a table. Each file has its id which I need to add into it. the corresp dictionary has file name and id couples. there is already an empty element in the xml, called idno[@type='TM'] in which I need to enter the corresponding id number.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DIR = 'files/'
corresp = {"00100004":"362375", "00100005":"362376", "00100006":"362377", "00100007":"362378"}

for fileName, tm in corresp.iteritems():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(DIR + fileName + ".xml")) 
    tmid = soup.find("idno", type="TM")
    tmid.append(tm)
    print soup
```

My first problem is that *some time* it works, some time it says

```
tmid.append(tm)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I have no idea why. yesterday evening I run the same sample code and now it complains in this way.

I have also tried etree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
DIR = 'files/'
corresp = {"00100004":"362375", "00100005":"362376", "00100006":"362377", "00100007":"362378"}
for fileName, tm in corresp.iteritems():
        f = open(DIR + fileName + ".xml")
        tree = ET.parse(f)
        tmid = tree.findall("//idno[@type='TM']")
        tmid.append(tm)
        tree.write('output.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

But it says "no element found: line 1, column 0"

My second, probably related problem is that when it did work, I was not able to write the output to a file. Ideally I would like to simply write it back to the file I am modifying.

Thank you very much for any advise on this.

Comment: try ---from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
DIR = 'files/'
root = os.path.abspath(DIR)
corresp = {"00100004":"362375", "00100005":"362376", "00100006":"362377", "00100007":"362378"}

for fileName, tm in corresp.iteritems():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(os.path.join(root,"fileName",".xml"))) 
    tmid = soup.find("idno", type="TM")
    tmid.append(tm)
    print soup

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

`find()` just returns the result. If `find()` can’t find anything, it returns None. both result and None are not a python list, so it does not have `append()` method.

check the doc:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Find does not returns list never so it would raises an exception (not the same exc) even if there were something found. Find_all returns list or empty list..

Comment: I see, so it means there isn't the idno in the file? there is actually... what about saving that change into the file?

Comment: @PietroMariaLiuzzo,  anwser is updated,  what is the traceback info about your second problem?

Comment: Thanks everyone! It was actually the case: in some previous attempt I had somehow emptied a file and this apparently blocked everything as it was not possible to find idno[@type='TM'] in there. As for the second problem I have apparently managed to sort it out with one more variable. and this for fileName, tm in corresp.iteritems():
 myfile = open(DIR + fileName + ".xml")
 soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile) 
 tmid = soup.find("idno", type="TM")
 tmid.append(tm)
 new = soup.prettify("UTF-8")
 myfile.close()
 with open(NewDIR + fileName + ".xml", "wb") as file:
     file.write(new)